# Parent specification in elasticsearch for first node

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk

I am using the _bulk api for indexing my data. I have a parent field for every document except the first document.

Normally my documents will have the following meta-data:

```
{"index":{"_id":"11111", "parent": "00000"}}
```

What should I specify in the parent field for the first document.

Should I leave the parent field blank?

```
{"index":{"_id":"00000", "parent": ""}}
```

Or should I not include the parent field at all?

```
{"index":{"_id":"00000"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply don't include the `parent` property at all in your first document, which should act as the parent document for all other documents.

Comment: I am using bulk api. Creating a string in Java. Persisting that string using bulki api. But it is giving 400 error.

Comment: Please show a relevant part of your bulk query and the error you're getting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030795/elasticsearch-bulk-api-returning-400-error-in-java